# How can I refresh a view every second to reflect changes in real time?

Tags: java, sql, swing, user-interface, netbeans

I'm writing an app for a manager to keep track of the goings-on of a factory that uses machines. Could I make a Swing interface that updates from an SQL database and constantly shows who is logged into each machine, the status of each machine and how many things are in the queue of each machine? All the machine info is in the database.

In short, how can I refresh a view every second so that it will reflect the real-time status of the factory floor?

Comment: What I'm asking is if it's bad practice to simply destroy the frame and recreate it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the [Java timer class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) at 1000 milliseconds and querying the mysql database. Provided your db latency is low, you should be able to update 1/second.

Comment: What about the view? Like, do I just destroy the panel and make a new one?

Comment: @dah - you will update the model, which will make the view refresh itself automatically.

Comment: Issue being that I don't want to use a table. I want to use a background image with some labels overtop.

Answer (score 2):

Or use a [ScheduledExecutorService](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/exinter.html)